# Php value gets truncated after mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have written the code below which computes a weighted mean value. The algorithm is correct but my problem is that when the value **$row['grade']** is eg: **9.5 it gets truncated to 9** and when the value is **10 it gets truncated to 1**. From some tests i believe that the problem occurs when the value is inserted to the array. I have tried everything i know but i can't get it to work. Any ideas? Here's the code below:

```
<?php 


require 'database_connect.php';
$username=$_SESSION["username"];    
$sql="SELECT dm,grade from subject,attends where username='$username' AND grade>='5' and subject_code=code";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$i=-1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $i=$i+1;
    $grade[$i]=$row['grade'];
    if($row['dm']<=2){
        $weight[$i]=1.0;
    }elseif($row['dm']<=4){
        $weight[$i]=1.5;
    }else{
        $weight[$i]=2.0;
    }

}
if($i>=0){
    $total=array_sum($weight);

    $part=0;
    for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++){
        echo $grade[$j].",";
        echo $weight[$j]."|||"; 
        $part=$part+$grade[$j]*$weight[$j];

    }
    $full=$part/$total;

    // echo round($full, 2);


}else{
    echo "0";
}




                      $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: post your db schema

Comment: `and subject_code=code` is that supposed to stand for pseudo code? If not, it's faling here.

Comment: **Side-note:** since you're just starting to code using database queries. Please learn as early as now the importance/use of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: `var_dump($row['grade'])` has `9.5`?

Comment: subject_code is the foreign key in the table attends that refers to the table subject in the code value

Comment: Put `$grade = array(); $weight = array()` before the `while` loop.

Comment: @chris85 it gives me the string(3) "9.5". I tried to make it from string to float but when i try to put it in the array it still gets truncated

Comment: @Aristos: what gets output when you put `var_dump($grade)` after the while loop?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil It worked!!!! thank you very much!!! Is there a way to give credits or something?

Comment: @Aristos: I have copied my comment to an answer - you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `$grade = array(); $weight = array();` before the while loop.

EDIT: It is always a good idea to initialize arrays prior to first use, because if `$grade` somehow happens to be a string, `$grade[0]` reference would then mean *first character of the string*, not *first element of an array*.

For PHP 5.4 and newer you could also write `$grade = []; $weight = [];`.